# Android Issue, adding/removing dialogs to listviews after/before http requests

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

In my app I do an async task to download information from my mysql db and then display it in a listview that uses a custom adapter that extends a baseadapter. Each row displays the same 3 columns of information for the object in seperate textviews.

So it looks like
Row1 : TextView1  -  TextView2 - TextView3
Row2 : TextView1  -  TextView2 - TextView3
Row3 : TextView1  -  TextView2 - TextView3
etc..

My question is, rather then having a one large dialog appear at the start of downloading all the information and making the user wait for it to update, is it possible to put a small dialog in each row and once it has updated, display the text where the dialog was?

So it would look like this at the beginning of updating:
Row1 : Dialog
Row2 : Dialog
Row3 : Dialog

Then after recieving all the information for row1:
Row1 : TextView1  -  TextView2 - TextView3
Row2 : Dialog
Row3 : Dialog
etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In fact one of the best practices for lists containing large data like images is to put in a stand in and then display it as soon as it is ready. To accomplish that you will need to create the stand in list, begin the async task to populate it, and upon completing a row call `onProgressUpdate()` to place it in the list properly and `notifyDataSetChanged()` to display it

Comment: What do you mean by using a stand? Like using a blank layout?

Comment: What you decide to put in to the list until the information is populated is up to you. It could be a generic icon, a spinner, or nothing at all. Whatever you want to indicate that something is coming, but not here yet. If you look at many android apps (like contact lists, or twitter) a generic picture is shown until the data is loaded.